# indication of Support value of classification_report for imbalanced class

Tags: scikit-learn, binary, classification, confusion-matrix

I have an imbalanced dataset where I am trying to do binary classification. I have used several algorithms finally `CatBoostClassifier` and `lightgbm` gave me comparative better results. I have a question to ask regarding the `classification_report` and the `confusion_matrix`.

As you can see from my `classification_report`:
-`True Negatives`:  1076,
-`False Positives`:  0,
-`False Negatives`:  1,
-`True Positives`:  6.

The `Sensitivity` : 0.86 and `Specificity` 1.00 , which means my `false positive rate` is 0.0.

I have a notion that it did perform really well.

From the `classification_report` does it tell you that my model might have overfitted or it indeed performed well?

I am asking this because the `support` of class `1` (which is less in number) is 7 whereas that of class `0` is 1076.

From [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/117671) it says that: *"The support is the number of samples of the true response that lie in that class."* But I don't really get the point here.

Can anybody explain to me or let me know if my algorithm did overfit or performed well?

Labels ratio:

```
0    5550
1      60
```

Classification report

```
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

         0.0       1.00      1.00      1.00      1076
         1.0       1.00      0.86      0.92         7

    accuracy                           1.00      1083
   macro avg       1.00      0.93      0.96      1083
weighted avg       1.00      1.00      1.00      1083
```

Confusion Matrix:

```
[[1076    0]
 [   1    6]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be able to understand things better if you look at the classification report of both the training set and the test set together, you just can't say anything for certain by just looking at either the performance on training set or on the train set alone. But if we assume that the performance measures that you have shown here are for the test set and that the performance in train set is also more or less similar to what you observe in the test set, then I would say that the model did a good job. The recall for class `1` is `86%` given the fact that it forms just `1%` of your dataset is quite good.

Also, support refers to the total number of examples belonging to a particular class in your dataset, for example in your case the support for class `0`  is `5550` and that for class `1` is `60`

Comment: Thanks for your comment and explanation. Yes indeed this is a classification report from the test set and I just checked the classification report for the train set. It is better than the test set. So I would then say based on your explanation that it did work well. Thanks again! :)

Comment: But how do I check if my model is overfitting or not?

Comment: If the performance on the train set is way higher than your test set then probably your model is overfitting..